# The Android share for MP4 only works for Facebook Messenger and not for other Apps

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share, mp4

I got some .mp4 files in my /raw folder which i want to share with the Android Share. The following code works with Facebook Messenger (the video is sended) but not with other applications like WhatsApp, Gmail, Facebook, etc.

I got the following code:

```
    String path = "android.resource://com.my.package/raw/" + "name_mp4";
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("video/mp4");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(path) );
    startActivity(share);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it nog work for the other Apps?

Comment: See if this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22667585/1064310

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Few apps will know what to do with an `android.resource` `Uri`. The ones that will mostly will be ones passing it straight to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. That scheme is very rarely used.

If you want to improve compatibility, use a `content://` or `file://` `Uri`, pointing at a `ContentProvider` or file on external storage, respectively.